# How to obtain the value of a single symbol with mathlink

Tags: mathlink-or-wstp

I am trying to write a (C) routine which reads the value (a list) assigned to a single symbol in mathlink. I tried things like

```
MLPutFunction(mathlink, "EvaluatePacket", 1L);
MLPutSymbol(mathlink, "mysymbol");
MLEndPacket(mathlink);
```

I have been using similar constructs for evaluating functions, but this does not seem to work. No return packet is received.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you probably misunderstood how this works. You don't have to explicitly *read* the list. Just setup an appropriate *MathLink template* and you can simply call your function and give you list as argument.

Please read the tutorial [Setting Up External Functions to Be Called from the Wolfram Language](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SettingUpExternalFunctionsToBeCalledFromTheWolframLanguage.html) and after this, the solution you are searching for is in the tutorial [Handling Lists, Arrays, and Other Expressions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/HandlingListsArraysAndOtherExpressions.html). The very first example should already be what you want

```
:Begin:
:Function:       h
:Pattern:        h[a_List]
:Arguments:      {a}
:ArgumentTypes:  {IntegerList}
:ReturnType:     Integer
:End:
```

```c
int h(int *a, long alen) {    
   int i, tot=0;
   for(i=0; i<alen; i++)
      tot += a[i];    
   return tot;
}
```

When you have compiled and installed (using `Install`) your program, then you can simply pass your list `l` by calling

```
h[l]
```

That's it.

Comment: I think that's about the opposite of what I want. I am trying to call a Mathematica module from within a C program.

Comment: @highsciguy OK, then I completely misinterpreted the *reads the value* part. Question: In your example you have send `mysymbol` for evaluation to *Mathematica*, but you don't read the returning packet. Why? You should use `WSCheckFunction` and `WSGetIntegerList` for that. Please [read here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TwoWayCommunicationWithExternalPrograms.html).

Comment: That's the part I was missing. I started to be unsure about it.